# Does jmeter create its own cookies?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a jmeter test where the http requests I am testing do not use any cookies. In the request body it shows as "[no cookies]". So ideally there should be no difference between checking or unchecking the "same user on each iteration" button. But in my tests there appears to be a slight decrease in throughput when the button is unchecked. Why is that happening ? Is it because jmeter is creating its own cookies somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

When the button is unchecked JMeter has to shut down the thread and kick off a new one, this causes the overhead you're observing. Starting a new thread is kind of "expensive" process, that's why there is [Thread Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) pattern.

The fact you're observing throughput decrease rings some bells because your assumption is correct, there should not be difference, if there is the difference it indicates that JMeter is acting at the edge of its possibilities so you might want to double check:

- whether you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- whether JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc. (can be visualized using i.e. [JMeter Perfmon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test))
- whether you want to consider switching to [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: @Dimitri T you explained that there is an overhead when the button is unchecked because the thread shuts down and a new one needs to be created. Can't this overhead be the reason for a slight decrease in throughput?